# Emacs blank square on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

My Emacs version:
[Emacs version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMNbe.jpg)

This is the screenshot, notice the blank square in the center:

[Emacs display problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blr0C.png)

I Guess this is because of the emacs plugin `better defaults`. However, the same emacs configuration works well on my Linux desktop including openSUSE Linux and Arch Linux. Anyone knows the reason? Thank you. ;-)

***update:***

I add `(setq visible-bell nil)` to init.el and problem solved. Thanks you for @lawlist help!

Comment: The blank or opaque square is almost always the visual bell.  There are a zillion threads about turning off the visual bell -- Google:  emacs visual bell off

Comment: @lawlist  I add `(setq visible-bell nil)` to init.el and problem solved. Thanks you so much!

Comment: @lawlist you should write this up as answer, it makes it clearer for future readers.

Comment: It's a known bug when running Emacs on El Capitan. It's been fixed in the upcoming Emacs 25 release.

Comment: @Lindydancer okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual bell (a square shaped image) can sometimes be opaque or clear.  To remove the visual bell, `(setq visible-bell nil)` should be placed inside the `.emacs` or `init.el` file.  The doc-string for the variable `visible-bell` states:  "*Non-nil means try to flash the frame to represent a bell.*"

Alternatively, the user may wish to create a custom `ring-bell-function` (which is beyond the scope of the question/answer).  To view more about that option, type `M-x describe-variable RET ring-bell-function RET`